# Merge dataframes via columnwise in a directory with common columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge multiple .txt files in a directory specifically merging on one of the common column `X` found in dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

  df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['X0', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3'],
       ...:                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
       ...:                     'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
       ...:                     'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']})


 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['X0', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3'],
   ...:                     'G': ['G0', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3'],
   ...:                     'H': ['H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3'],
   ...:                     'J': ['J0', 'J1', 'J2', 'J3']})
```

by following previous this post
[Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)
and this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

I tried

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.iglob(filepath + '/*.txt', recursive=True):

    print(file)

    df=pd.read_csv(file, sep ='\t',header=0, skiprows=0, skipfooter=0, na_values=(""," ","NA"))
    data=pd.concat([data,df])

data_merge = pd.merge(data,on='X',how='inner')
```

but I got

> TypeError: merge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'

How can I join two datafame by common `X` column?

the expected output

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: you can use `pd.merge` either with: `df1.merge(df2, on='X')`, or `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='X')`, they're the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concat` is enough, you don't need `merge`. Do `data = []`, read the files in to dataframes, append them to `data` and `concat` once:

```
data = []
for file in glob.iglob(filepath + '/*.txt', recursive=True):

    print(file)

    df=pd.read_csv(file, sep ='\t',header=0, skiprows=0, skipfooter=0, na_values=(""," ","NA"))
    data.append(df.set_index('X'))

data_merge = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
```

This assumes that your `X` columns do not contain duplicates in all the dataframes. Otherwise, you need to do iterative `merge` inside the `for` loop without `concat`, somthing like:

```
final_df = None
for file in glob.iglob(filepath + '/*.txt', recursive=True):

    print(file)

    df=pd.read_csv(file, sep ='\t',header=0, skiprows=0, skipfooter=0, na_values=(""," ","NA"))
    if final_df is not None:
        final_df = final_df.merge(df, on='X', how='outer')
    else: 
        final_df = df
```

Comment: What if I have multiple common columns like ['Z', 'Q', 'W']

Comment: and `merge` is more way flexible than `concat` in terms of join options.

Comment: `set_index(['Z','Q','W'])` instead of `set_index('X')`. You can also pass `index_cols=['Z','Q','W']` to `read_csv` and forget about `set_index`.

Comment: what does `if final_df is not None:` do here ? checkign the data file is emtpy or not ?

Comment: It checks if this is the first file or not. You can also do `final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns='X')` and get rid of that `if` check.

Comment: Thanks! This is great!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't including the right dataframe to merge on, as in you are only giving the merge call a single dataframe when it needs both. Try:
`pd.merge(df1, df2, on="X")`

Edit:

```
dataframe_list = []
for file in glob.iglob(filepath + '/*.txt', recursive=True):

    print(file)

    data=pd.read_csv(file, sep ='\t',header=0, skiprows=0, skipfooter=0, na_values=(""," ","NA"))
    dataframe_list.append(data)

data_merge = pd.merge(dataframe_list[0], dataframe_list[1], on='X',how='inner')
```

---

Edit 2, more than two dataframes:

```
dataframe_list = []
for file in glob.iglob(filepath + '/*.txt', recursive=True):

    print(file)

    data=pd.read_csv(file, sep ='\t',header=0, skiprows=0, skipfooter=0, na_values=(""," ","NA"))
    dataframe_list.append(data)

    if len(dataframe_list) ==2:
        data_merge = pd.merge(dataframe_list[0], dataframe_list[1], on='X')
        dataframe_list = [data_merge]
dataframe = dataframe_list[0]
```

Comment: Cannot do that. Everything in a for loop. Please check OP carefully.

Comment: In that case I would make a list of dataframes, fill it with data from each file, then merge the contents of the list, like this:

Comment: can you send a solution for that?

Comment: what if I have 100 files in the folder ? we need to do dataframe_list[0], dataframe_list[1], dataframe_list[2], dataframe_list[3]....dataframe_list[99] ?

Comment: I would just merge contents when the list is two items large, then reset the list. added in edit

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It really helped!